# How do I return a List from a JSON object?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webclient

I'm building my first app in Xamarin Forms which will read information from a SQL Database through a web request.
I've come to the point where I successfully read and display information in a WinForms application. Though, in Xamarin Forms I can't seem to get the same result.

On the Main Page I call:

```
var jobService = new JobService();
listView.ItemsSource = jobService.JobList(DatePicker.Date);
```

Then, in the JobService class this is my code.

```
class JobService
{
    List<Job> jobs;
    string userId; 
    string date;

    public List<Job> JobList(DateTime datetime)
    {
        userId = 1234;
        date = datetime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");

        Client();
        return jobs;
    }

    public void Client()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://Location/webservice.php");
        NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();

        parameters.Add("UserId", userId);
        parameters.Add("Date", date);

        client.UploadValuesCompleted += Client_UploadValuesCompleted;
        client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, parameters);
    }

    public void Client_UploadValuesCompleted(object sender, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        jobs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Job>>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result));
    }
```

In WinForms this is my code

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://Location/webservice.php");
        NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();

        parameters.Add("UserId", 1234);
        parameters.Add("Date", datetime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));

        client.UploadValuesCompleted += Client_UploadValuesCompleted;
        client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, parameters);
    }

    private void Client_UploadValuesCompleted(object sender, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Job> jobs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Job>>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result));           
        MessageBox.Show(jobs[0].Project); //Project is one of the properties of the Job Class
    }
```

This is the Job Class:

```
public class Job
{
    [JsonProperty("Project")]
    public string Project { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Service")]
    public string Service { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Client")]
    public string Client { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("StartTime")]
    public string StartTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("EndTime")]
    public string EndTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

While debugging the Xamarin solution I noticed that `jobs` returns as `null`. Is it being returned before  `UploadValuesAsync` is completed?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 (16.6.0), .NET version 4.8. I'm also using the Newtonsoft.Json Packet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the JSON structured? Do you have an example? What about your `Job` class?

Comment: Hi! I've added the job class to the post. An example: I send a username and date to the php webservice. It returns a JSON object with the properties listed in the Job Class. I'm new to this so I'm not sure how the JSON is exactly structured, but I can deserialize it to a list. In the PHP file i call ''echo json_encode($list);' Is that of any use?

Comment: What I meant by an example is to have the actual JSON content. In your code, you have a `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result)`. What does that contain? If it doesn't match with the structure you defined, it will fail just as you saw. From a first look, I suspect it might be the `JsonProperty` attributes you use. Most likely, they will need to be `project`, `service`, `client` etc.

Comment: Hi Sotiris, thanks for your help! The JSON string that is returned looks like this: [{"Project":"Project1","Service":"Knitting","Client":"Client1","StartTime":"09:00","EndTime":"17:00","Date":"01-01-2020"}]. The Job Class is the same in the WinForms project, where it works. That would rule out changing the property names right?

Comment: Try to make your `Client()` as `Task<void>` and make `await Client();` in `JobList`

Comment: JobList is calling Client() but not waiting for it to complete before returning.  You need to read up on async/await

Comment: Yes I think you're right Jason. All the test I've done suggest that. I'll dive into async/await more :)

Comment: Also consider using HttpClient, which is a much more modern implementation comparing to WebClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your responses. I fixed the problem by using `HttpClient` and learning more about `async` / `await`. This is my code. Honestly I feel like I still don't know enough about this topic to be confident about it, so if anyone thinks the code can be cleaner, feel free to eleborate :)

This is my current (working) code:

On the MainPage I call:

```
var jobService = new JobService();
var jobList = await jobService.JobListAsync(DatePickerInvisible.Date); //I will use this list for further display actions.
```

Then, in the JobService class this is my code:

```
class JobService
{
    string userId; 
    string date;
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; private set; }
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public async Task<List<Job>> JobListAsync(DateTime datetime)
    {
        userId = 1234;
        date = datetime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");

        Jobs = new List<Job>();
        var uri = new Uri("http://Location/webservice.php");

        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queries = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserId", userId),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Date", date)
        };

        HttpContent q = new FormUrlEncodedContent(queries);

        try
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, q);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Jobs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Job>>(content);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return Jobs;
    }
}
```

The Job Class remains the same.

Thanks again for helping me. Your comments combined put me on the right path.